# Installing or Building something

Tags: compilation

What is the difference between "Installing xyz from pre-built binaries" and "building xyz from source". ? I tried to look for general meaning but no answer was straightforward!

Answer (score 0):

When one builds from source, binaries get produced; with pre-built binaries, the step to produce those binaries has already been done.

Answer (score 0):

Well, installing pre-built binaries are file or programs pre-compiled in another machine. Now building from source gives the advantage to use your compiler set and control how and with what will be compiled. e.g. If you download a source and compile your self those files and use high optimizer compiler (say Intel) you could gain very noticeable performance on your applications as oppose to standard gcc. Of course Intel has cost, gcc is free, but there are several free compilers out there that will optimize your source code.